# Why is this not drawn as an perfect square?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Here is my code:

```js
let pixelSize = 5;
let width = 100;
let height = 100;

function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {

            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(255 - 30 * i) + ', ' +
                Math.floor(255 - 30 * j) + ', 0)';

            ctx.fillRect(j * pixelSize, i * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
        }
    }
}
draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    canvas{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

<script src="mandelbrot.js"></script>
</html>
```

I would expect it to draw an perfect square but it does not

If i set the width and height to about 10 x 10 it is an square
But as soon as i go above 80 or so it becomes an rectangle

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot and highlight the problem? I’m not sure which non-square rectangle you’re talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that your canvas size is too small and it's clipping the image to the size. You're drawing the pixels correctly, it's just outside the bounds of the canvas. Try setting the width & height of the canvas element to something large enough to hold your image:

```js
let pixelSize = 5;
let width = 100;
let height = 100;

function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {

            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(255 - 30 * i) + ', ' +
                Math.floor(255 - 30 * j) + ', 0)';

            ctx.fillRect(j * pixelSize, i * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
        }
    }
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Where are you setting the width and height of the canvas in that code?

Comment: CSS `width` and `height` properties don’t set the width and height of the drawing area, though. They just stretch it. (If you run your code snippet, you’ll see the squares are twice as tall as they are wide because the default size is 300×150.)

Comment: Thank you this fixed it!